# How to retrieve Data from Mysql based on DatePicker Selection?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have a page where I am showing a jquery datepicker with some highlighted dates. How do I retrieve data and populate a div based on a date clicked in the date picker.  Here is my code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

var dates = [new Date(2011, 9-1, 20), new Date(2011, 9-1, 21),new Date(2011, 10-1, 1)];

$(function(){

    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: [1,1],
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        beforeShowDay: highlightDays
    });

    function highlightDays(date) {
        for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
            if (dates[i].getTime() == date.getTime()) {
                return [true, 'highlight'];
            }
        }
        return [true, ''];   
    }  

});
</script>

<style>

#highlight, .highlight {
    background-color: #cc0000;
}

</style>  


</head>
<body style="font-size:62.5%;">

<div id="datepicker"></div>

<div id="events">
Data From Mysql To Go Here
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

well, you will need to do an ajax call to a serverside script (php or asp.net or any serverside language/framework of your choosing)

**edit** after seeing you want the code to happen on selecting a date, i changed the javascript a little **end edit**

like this:

```
//add the onSelect function to your date picker, and put the code to fetch your events in there
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
  numberOfMonths: [1,1],
  dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
  beforeShowDay: highlightDays,
  onSelect: function(date){
    // put your selected date into the data object
    var data = {'date': date};

    // do the ajax call to the serverside script and pass 'data' to it.
    $.get("serverurl/data/getdata.php", data, function(data){
      // this function is called upon successfully completing the ajax call
      //do your magic here to put the data elements into your div, see below for an example
      data.Events.each(function(d){
        var e = $('<div/>').text(d.Title);
        $('#events').append(e);
      });
    });
  }
});
```

this would however require you to have your getdata.php return proper json like this:

```
{
  Events: [ {
      Title: "event 1", 
      Description: "event description"
    }, 
    {
      Title: "event 2", 
      Description: "event description"
    } ]
}
```

Comment: lost me a bit here #button ?  is clicking a date in the date picker automatically given an ID of button?

Comment: i changed the code around, i thought you would have a button, but you want it imediately after selecting a date, so i used the onSelect event of the datepicker

Comment: i have it figured out but i cant post what i worked out for 6 hours so ill try and post what i got working and wanted tomorrow.  Thanks for your help